# Android Studio crashing when timepicker is placed in xml

Tags: android-studio, timepicker

My android studio crashes whenever i try to render a timepicker in the xml. I have to end the process in taskmgr. As the timepicker is a central part of my app its fairly necessary. This occurs even in brand new projects which otherwise have nothing in. However if i insert the code into the XMLs text file and then run the app on an avm it runs correctly? I am running windows 10, however am running as administrator.